# Working with Response Data in Global Context with Request Library

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

With the following code, I'm able to console.log the data that I need for a project. However, given that the data variable is local, I'm having trouble exporting it for use in the global context, so I can use this data in another file in my project. The error is that the 'data' is not defined when console logging this data in the other file. Could somebody explain why the following won't export, and potential resolutions?

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio")
var request = require("request")
var promise = require("promise")

var data;

request('https://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/full-fantasy-basketball-projections', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html)
    var variable = $('script')[1].children[0].data
    data = variable.substring(variable.indexOf("= ")+2, variable.indexOf(";"))
  }
})

module.exports = data;
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as [tag:promise]? The code conains no promises. Also, what you're asking for is pretty much impossible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`request` is a `async` function and this code will be run at the time module be required. But when the time code run, data still be `undefined`.

`module.exports = undefined;`

And later you can't get private `data` value by variable pointer.

**Before request**

module.exports -> undefined

data -> undefined

**After request**

module.exports -> undefined (it can't point to data variable!!!!)

data -> variable.substring(variable.indexOf("= ")+2, variable.indexOf(";"))